# Retrofit complains about this json not being an array

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit2, jsonparser

I know this has been asked many times, but I didn't find my solution.

```
Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
```

My json, I'm expecting an array Model[]:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "category": "Category 1",
    "question": "Bla bla",
    "answer": "<p>Bla bla bla.</p>\n",
    "lastModified": "2018-05-24T12:28:37.41"
},{
    "id": 2,
    "category": "Category 1",
    "question": "Bla bla",
    "answer": "<p>Bla bla bla.</p>\n",
    "lastModified": "2018-05-24T12:28:37.41"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "category": "Category 1",
    "question": "Bla bla",
    "answer": "<p>Bla bla bla.</p>\n",
    "lastModified": "2018-05-24T12:28:37.41"
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "category": "Category 1",
    "question": "Bla bla",
    "answer": "<p>Bla bla bla.</p>\n",
    "lastModified": "2018-05-24T12:28:37.41"
}]
```

If I copy the response from the server and:

```
final String response = "...";
final Gson gson = new Gson();
final FAQ[] faqs = gson.fromJson(response, FAQ[].class);
Log.d("TAG", "TEST: " + faqs[0].getAnswer());
```

This is working as expected...what is possibly wrong with the server response?

EDIT: interface:

```
@Headers({
        "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language: it-IT"
})
@GET("faq")
Call<FAQ[]> getFAQs(@Query(Constants.API_PARAM_PAGE) int page,
                    @Query(Constants.API_PARAM_PAGE_SIZE) int pageSize);
```

Comment: What does your interface mapping look like?

Comment: You have some special quotation marks at least in the JSON in the question. Sites like [https://jsoneditoronline.org/](https://jsoneditoronline.org/) and [https://jsonlint.com/](https://jsonlint.com/) for example are handy for checking your JSON.

Comment: please copy and paste your interface of method that calls the api

Comment: I've edited my question with the interface. The special quotation was just a copy paste issue...

Answer (score 1):

Solved my own issue removing:

```
"Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br"
```

If you provide that header, Retrofit expect you'll provide your own decompression implementation. I need holiday.